# How to create a custom (reusable) feature for filter menus

Tags: angular, filter, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a custom filter that matches the one from the Kendo docs:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/filtering/reusable-filter/

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-dropdown-filter',
    template: `
    <kendo-dropdownlist 
      [data]="data"
      (valueChange)="onChange($event)" 
      [defaultItem]="defaultItem"
      [value]="selectedValue" 
      [valuePrimitive]="true"
      [textField]="textField"
      [valueField]="valueField">
    </kendo-dropdownlist>
  `
})
export class DropDownListFilterComponent extends BaseFilterCellComponent {

    public get selectedValue(): any {
        const filter = this.filterByField(this.valueField);
        return filter ? filter.value : null;
    }

    @Input() public filter: CompositeFilterDescriptor;
    @Input() public data: any[];
    @Input() public textField: string;
    @Input() public valueField: string;

    public get defaultItem(): any {
        return {
            [this.textField]: "Select item...",
            [this.valueField]: null
        };
    }

    constructor(filterService: FilterService) {
        super(filterService);
    }

    public onChange(value: any): void {
        this.applyFilter(
            value === null ? // value of the default item
                this.removeFilter(this.valueField) : // remove the filter 
                this.updateFilter({ // add a filter for the field with the value
                    field: this.valueField,
                    operator: "eq",
                    value: value
                })
        ); // update the root filter
    }
}
```

It works fine with "row" style grid filters. However, when I try to change it to the "menu" style the filter applies whenever the dropdown is changed. Every other filter in that style requires you to click the "Filter" button. If I change the code in the change handler to:

```
public onChange(value: any): void {
    if (value) {
        this.updateFilter({ // add a filter for the field with the value
            field: this.valueField,
            operator: 'eq',
            value: value
        })
    }
    else {
        this.removeFilter(this.valueField);
    }
}
```

Then the filter button feature works as expected; but it doesn't actually filter the grid. I am *expecting* there to be some method to override that is called when "Filter" is clicked but have had no luck finding it. I've also tried just setting the filter property (same effect) or using `applyFilter` which just immediately filters again.

How do you use custom filter components with the "menu" style filters in Kendo Angular Grids?

Answer (score 2):

When customizing the Filter menus you need to use the *kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate* directive (instead of the *kendoGridFilterCellTemplate* one).

[Step-by-step explanation of the process and a runnable example are available in the docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/filtering/built-in-template/#toc-customizing-filter-menus).

Comment: I understand that; but I still have the problem listed above (it doesn't work at all unless I follow the steps you mention). I did not however, find that sample. I'll compare it to my code and see what is different. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have to manually handle filter change... there has to be a better option than that.